# RegEx to check if the digits in a number are all the same or in sequence

Tags: java, regex

I want to check if the user's input in the server side.
If the user enters a number 111111 or 22222 which has the same numbers,
and also if the input is in sequence like 12345 or 456789.

Comment: What about 8910?  Is that a 'sequence'?

Comment: What about 2335777, is that "in sequence"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To match consecutive same digits:

```
^([0-9])\1*$
```

Note that you have to escape the backslash when you put it in a java string literal, for example,

```java
"^([0-9])\\1*$"
```

For the second one you have to explicitly make a list of consecutive digits using the `|` operator. The regex would be really long and nasty with as many as 10-nested parantheses. One has to generate this regex using a program. In other words, this is a wrong problem to solve using regex. It would be much simpler to write a loop and test this.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Solving with RegEx is really nasty. I solved it with good old friend for loop. Thanks for help.

Comment: @SusamPal, (4 years later...) cool (+1)! please see my answer for the second.

Comment: how can we can make negate of this regex to work with javax.validation.constraints @Pattern

Answer (score 4):

This pattern will match if the user enters the same digit:

```
^(\d)\1*$
```

`\1` matches the first capture group, so the pattern matches whether that first digit is repeated for the entire string.

The second problem (consecutive digits) is somewhat more difficult.

```
^(?:^(?:^(?:^(?:^0?1)?2)?3)4?)?5(?:$|6(?:$|7(?:$|8(?:$|90?))))$|
    ^(0?1)?2(?:$|3(?:$|4))|^(6?7)?8(?:$|90?)$
```

is one implementation, assuming three or more digits.  But since the number of combinations is small, enumerating (4+ digits) is also possible:

```
^(?:0?123(45?)?|1?23456?|2?34567?|3?45678?|4?56789?|(5?6)?7890?|
         (0?1)?2345678?(90$)?|1?23456789?|2?345678(90?)?)$
```

All this said, regular expressions don't always work well for this type of problem.  A Java method to check for this sequence might be cleaner.

Comment: The second regex doesn't match strings like "123", "345", etc. Edit: Okay, I now see that you have assumed "6 digits".

Comment: thanks Susam, I saw that 6 digits wasn't a requirement and edited the post to make it more general.

Comment: that solves if the number start with 0 or 1 i think. For loop was much useful. Thanx btw.

Answer (score 1):

This time in perl, to explain the second case easier:

```
perl -nlE 'say "BAD number" if ($_ =~ /^(\d)\1*$/ or "123456789" =~ /$_/)'
```

Explanation:

- case 1 : input ∈ `/(\d)\1*/` language: already presented (`$_ =~ /^(\d)\1*$/`)
- case 2 : string "123456789" matches input (`"123456789" =~ /$_/`)