# Regex for non repetitive and with exact length for numbers

Tags: java

I want to check for zip i.e. if zip should have 5 digits exactly like 12346 and also it shouldn't have repetitive consecutive numbers like 00000, 11111 ,22222 .... 99999 what will be the regex to check for this validation ? I need two regular expressions in this case combining one positive and one negative which i.e. to find number which should have exact 5 digit and should not have repetitive numbers like 11111 , 22222 etc..

Comment: This is not duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870494/regex-to-check-if-the-digits-in-a-number-are-all-the-same-or-in-sequence as that question doesn't combines two regular expressions but in this case two regular expressions are needed and to be combined..

Comment: Looks like exactly the same problem to me.  There is no reasonable way to make a regex for a sequence that is not five identical characters.  Any solution will be quite unwieldy.  My first instinct would be to use `!zip.matches("([0-9])\\1{4}")`.

Comment: This is tantamount to a 'category error'. You're trying to apply a tool to a problem for which it's not suited. You might be able to use a regex to eliminate stuff such as -non-digits, but you're going to have to check rules are met programatically. I doubt even the problem is even defined properly since I'm guessing that *some* repetition of digits is possible.

Comment: I am using @Pattern javax validation constraints on zip field so I need to have regex pattern combining two patterns..

Comment: You probably will need to create your own validation annotation type, which itself must be annotated with [@Constraint](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/Constraint.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx to check if the digits in a number are all the same or in sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870494/regex-to-check-if-the-digits-in-a-number-are-all-the-same-or-in-sequence)

Comment: No Steven i require two regex to be combined in this case..

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to do this with custom ConstraintValidator as follows:

```
 public class ZipCodeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidateZip, String> {

   @Override
   public boolean isValid(String zip, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
       return zip.matches("(^[\\d]{5}$){1}") && !zip.equals(APPConstants.ZIP_ALL_ZEROES);
   }

}
```

and with annotation:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = ZipCodeValidator.class)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface ValidateZip {

    String message() default "Resident Zip Code not valid from request, unable to process.";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

then using this annotation on field where validation is required:

```
@ValidateZip
public String residentPostalcode;
```